# ASP.NET cannot get data from external url

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I've tried everything and i am guessing i have a codeblock.

I am using this aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.amazon.com/");
        string data = "";
        if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
        {
        try{
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();

            this.Panel1.GroupingText = tmp;
            }
            catch(WebException ex){
            Response.Write(ex.Status);
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"
            Height="355px" Width="480px" ScrollBars="Auto">
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could there be anything wrong in my iis. I am using localhost from port 80.

Maybe i need to provide more data, if so, please tell me.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you getting? an exception?

Comment: if you plan to crwl a webpage why doun´t you use html agility pack? http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes this exception:

catch(WebException ex){
            Response.Write(ex.Status);
            }
wich says: TimeOut

Comment: try to set a bigger timeout for the request and try to determinate using request.Timeout=100000; if you are still getting a timeout error try to see if you don´t have issues with a firewall and the port you are trying to do the request...

Comment: When i do that i get this as output: ConnectFailure

Comment: seems like a possible network error....

Comment: how can i check in iis what else could be the problem, because i don't think it would be on the amazon side

Comment: try to set a proxy in your web request for more info take a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms346609.aspx